# NSTimeInterval display incorrect time interval

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode

After adding a comment i need to show comment timing like year ago,day ago,minutes ago and second ago on label but it returns -4425,-33434 seconds ago "random numbers".

Here is my code shown below am using in my app.

```
NSString *inDateStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[dict objectForKey:@"d"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row-1] objectForKey:@"created"]];
NSString *s = @"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

// about input date(GMT)
NSDateFormatter *inDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
inDateFormatter.dateFormat = s;
inDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT-7.00"];
NSDate *inDate = [inDateFormatter dateFromString:inDateStr];

// about output date(IST)
NSDateFormatter *outDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
outDateFormatter.timeZone = [NSTimeZone localTimeZone];
outDateFormatter.dateFormat = s;
NSString *outDateStr = [outDateFormatter stringFromDate:inDate];

// final output
NSLog(@"[in]%@ -> [out]%@", inDateStr, outDateStr);

NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateStartingString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
NSString *datestartString = outDateStr;

dateStartingString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:datestartString];

NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [[NSDate date] timeIntervalSinceDate:dateStartingString];



double minutes = timeDifference / 60;
double hours = minutes / 60;
double seconds = timeDifference;
double days = minutes / 1440;

UILabel * dateLbl=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(155, [[CountArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] floatValue]-1, 80, 20)];
if(seconds>=86400)
    dateLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f days ", days];
else if(seconds>=3600 && seconds<86400 )
    dateLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f hours ", hours];
else if (seconds>=60 && seconds<3600 )
    dateLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f minutes ", minutes];
else
    dateLbl.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f seconds ", seconds];

dateLbl.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];
dateLbl.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
[cell.contentView addSubview:dateLbl];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe NSDateFormatter only takes a string and returns a NSDate object. Setting the timezone is meant for setting the property of NSDate, but doesn't actually convert the time provided. So in the end if you put in 5:30 GMT, you will get 5:30 IST.

You would instead want to use NSCalender to do timezone conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this method to get difference in date.
Make sure that date formate is correct. If you are getting negative value just check date format.

```
-(NSDateComponents *)getDateDifference:(NSString *)date
{
    NSDate *dateA=[NSDate date]; //Current date
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    NSDate *dateB = [dateFormatter dateFromString:date];//Convert nsstring to nsdate


    NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar]; //Gregorian allocation
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSDayCalendarUnit|NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSYearCalendarUnit
                                               fromDate:dateA
                                                 toDate:dateB
                                                options:0]; //Get day and hour

    return components;
}


// Call method like 
NSDateComponents *difference = [self getDateDifference:marriageDate];
NSLog(@"diff year = %f",difference.year);
```

Comment: what if i need minutes and seconds too?

Comment: you can add NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit in components. date formate just add HH:mm:ss also. Let me know if its work.